# Flickr limit on displayed photos

Tags: image, limit, flickr

Is there some limit of maximum number of Flickr photos, which I could put on single URL? Something like this:

```
<a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7065/6862159450_c16aa57f6a_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7065/6862159450_c16aa57f6a_s.jpg">
</a>
<a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7127/7008274819_c0159a6b2b_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7127/7008274819_c0159a6b2b_s.jpg">
</a>
<a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7243/7008274599_b414b0e4ff_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7243/7008274599_b414b0e4ff_s.jpg">
</a>
....
<!-- and 100 other photos... -->
```

I already know photos ID from our DB (so there will be no special API requests), I just need to make sure, that I could so many `<img>` tag on single page.

Two or three years ago I build some website, and I roughly remember that there **was** some limit. I tried to check this limit now, but I am not able to find this information on their site.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/tos/ 1.b.iii: "[You shall not] Display more than 30 Flickr user photos per page in your application or use an unreasonable amount of bandwidth."

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much Wooble! (so they still have this limit)